# Casting String to Date

Tags: sql, plsql

The below one is working fine and returns date in the desired format

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(max(entdate), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as last_transaction_date from table;
```

After adding hh24:mm:ss and error of "format code appears twice" ORA-01810 appears

```
  select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(max(entdate), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mm:ss'), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mm:ss') as last_transaction_date from table;
```

I'm not able to understand the difference between both cases

Comment: Casting a date to a string and then back to a date seems unnecessary.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MI not MM for minutes

"Some people mistakenly use the MM format code to represent minutes, thus using the MM format for both the months and the minutes."

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(max(entdate), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as last_transaction_date from table;
```

Comment: thank you so much Mardoxx, it didn't return the error but date is still returned in AM/PM format

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. PM should display the meridian indicator. HH24 should just display the hour of the day from 00 to 23.